# How to find the direction cosines of the line which bisects the angle positive degrees between positive direction of Y and Z axes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a text book solution like -

## The line bisects angle between Y and Z axes. Therefore the line lies in the YZ plane. Hence the X-axis is perpendicular to the line.

Now how come X-axis is perpendicular to the line in question if the fig. for this problem is like below where X-axis clearly doesn't look perpendicular to the line in question.

[image]

Comment: Figures are generally not drawn to scale

Comment: agreed...but there should at least be some coherence to what is being claimed in textbook answer, because if the bisecting line has to be perpendicular to x-axis it cannot exist in yz plane but rather in xy plane..please tell me how i am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this photo of a book:

[image]
The two edges of the book meeting at a corner do not meet at 90 degrees in the photo.

What we learn from this simple example is the projection from 3 dimensions to 2 dimensions generally does not preserve angles.

On the other hand, the $x$-axis is perpendicular to both the $y$ and $z$ axes, and hence (by bi-linearity of dot product, if you like) is perpendicular to any linear combination of them, hence to their bisector.

Comment: ok by that logic even if the bisecting line exists in xy or xz plane it will still be perpendicular to all the axes from a 3d perspective..like that of a cube

Comment: @ShaikhSakib: yes, the line perpendicular to the plane is perpendicular to any line in that plane.

Comment: hmm..that explains it..have accepted your answer @JohnHughes. Thank you.